# NameError Uninitialized Constant in rails for existing table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

I'm a bit stuck on a problem here in Rails that I feel may have a simple solution.

I have a class called "CircuitVw" which looks like the following

```
class CircuitVw < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'mvw_circuits'
  self.primary_key = :serv_item_id
```

Inside the controller, I've been able to pull back data using the following format

```
CircuitVw.all().order("customer_name DESC").each do | circuit |
      @customer[ "#{circuit.customer_name}" ] = circuit.psr
  end
```

However, when I try and access the table written this way, I get an uninitialized constant

```
MVW_CIRCUITS.where("activity_ind IN ( 'Pending', 'In Progress')").order("document_number DESC").each do | circuit |
      @psr[ "#{circuit.psr}  -  #{circuit.customer_name}" ] = circuit.psr
      end
```

Even though I can say something like

```
SELECT * FROM MVW_CIRCUITS
```

And return the entire table in the console for my staging environment.

What am I doing wrong here?

The table exists in the schema as

```
create_table "mvw_circuits", id: false, force: true do |t|
```

for reference.

Thanks for any insights you might have! Maybe I'm forgetting something dumb.  Appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `CircuitVw` to access or refer to the table `mvw_circuits`. You specified that in the `CircuitVw` class. So `MVW_CIRCUITS` is an uninitialized constant.

Try this one

```
CircuitVw.where("activity_ind IN ('Pending', 'In Progress')")
```

Comment: so why is it I can query the table in the db console by using mvw_cirucuts?  Just curious why if the table is named like that I can't.  It ALWAYS has to be by model name, not by table name?

Comment: SQL is a story, your application another one. The SQL table name is `MVW_CIRCUITS`. But in your application you access it via `CircuitVw` class.